# How is it being specified which segment register should be used (x86)

Tags: memory-management, x86, x86-64, addressing-mode, memory-segmentation

Here's a function:

```
void    func(char *ptr)
{
    *ptr = 42;
}
```

Here's an output (cut) of gcc -S function.c:

```
func:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    movq    %rdi, -8(%rbp)
    movq    -8(%rbp), %rax
    movb    $42, (%rax)
    nop
    popq    %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
```

I can use that function as:

```
func(malloc(1));
```

or as:

```
char local_var;
func(&local_var);
```

The question is how does processor determine which segment register should be used to transform the effective address to virtual one in this instruction (it may be DS as well as SS)

```
movb    $42, (%rax)
```

I have a x86_64 proc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default segment is DS; that’s what the processor uses in your example.

In 64-bit mode, it doesn’t matter what segment is used, because the segment base is always 0 and permissions are ignored. (There are one or two minor differences, which I won’t go into here.)

In 32-bit mode, most OSes set the base of all segments to 0, and sets their permissions the same, so again it doesn’t matter.

In code where it does matter (especially 16 bit code that needs to use more than 64 KB of memory), the code must use far pointers, which include the segment selector as part of the pointer value. The software must load the selector into a segment register in order to perform the memory access.

Comment: So, as i understand, the error "Segmentation fault" means nothing and modern OSes don't have segments actually? Why are there a lot of articles on habr that are describing different segments (text(code) segment, data, stack, heap) then?

Comment: Segmentation fault and segment registers are not related. They happen to use the same word but with different meanings. (Most processors don't have segment registers, but all Unix systems call access violations segmentation faults.)

Comment: Software-defined segments (text, data, bss, etc.) are also unrelated to hardware segments and segment registers.

Comment: @RaymondChen can you clarify me plz what's difference between them? If segment registers are not used by the modern OSes, is there another way that OSes use to logically divide memory? How does Linux protect memory with code from changing?

Comment: Modern OSes use paging for memory protection.

Comment: @prl if i create some string literal and will try to change it at runtime it will cause the segfault, so if there's only paging mechanism it sounds like OS stores permissions for each page(sounds not right). Can you clarify me how it works?